# jquery code insert googleads inside (.after)

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery code insert googleads inside
below is my js code,need place google ads code into 
jquery .after() or .html()
but it doesn't work..

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
 var  content = $('.cldesc').find('p, br,div');
 var  midLength = parseInt(content.length/2);
 content.eq(midLength).after('<div class="advbg"><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-8239618654141130" data-ad-slot="6511565608" data-ad-format="auto"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></div>'); });
</script>
```

Comment: are u using any ad service?

Comment: who can answer this?:

Comment: shanshank   google ads need put between , now the problem is it  will placed into html code, and will become bug     <div class="embeddedContent oembed-provider-youtube" data-align="none" data-oembed="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEzTBCLS7hE" data-oembed_provider="youtube" data-resizetype="noresize"><iframe... YOUR ADS CODEallowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EEzTBCLS7hE?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=1S03I" width="425"></iframe></div>

Comment: YOUR ADS CODE  show inside the iframe tag...

Comment: update new question

Answer (score 1):

You can break your php code and insert the HTML codes for the AD.

```
<?php
//your PHP code
?>

//your advertisement code
div class="embeddedContent oembed-provider-youtube" data-align="none" data-oembed="youtube.com/watch?v=EEzTBCLS7hE"; data-oembed_provider="youtube" data-resizetype="noresize">
<iframe... YOUR ADS CODEallowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="youtube.com/embed/…; width="425"></iframe>
</div>

<?php
//your PHP code
?>
```

Comment: i explain my problem, now my site is a user post system, mean user can post by ckeditor , the post may got htmlt tag like  <p> <img><a><b><iframe> and more.  i just need insert to middle to the post , i got try by strrpos(substr   divided to two part, but it will failed , because it divided even html tag